# How to get to the Threads View in VS

Tags: wpf, multithreading, concurrency, visual-studio-2013, profiling

I want to know how to get to this view [image: here], I've tried a lot with profiling in visual studio and this is nowhere to be seen.

Thanks.

Comment: Here you can download it first
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/24b56e51-fcc2-423f-b811-f16f3fa3af7a/file/106496/2/Microsoft.ConcurrencyVisualizer.vsix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the [Concurrency Visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537632.aspx) as one of the included [Diagnostic tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264943.aspx) which I think is an added extension, you can access it through Analyze->Concurrency Visualizer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it under Analyze menu and then Concurrency Visualizer.